# Apply XSLT template to string returned from function

Tags: xml, templates, xslt, xslt-1.0, apply-templates

*(all code here is simplified from it's original version)*

My company has a function used in XSLT (1.0) which returns the content from a file from our file system.  I need to be able to parse the return of the function using `apply-templates`.  Consider the following example:

**Main XML File:**

```
<exhibit>
    <exhibitTitle>Exhibit</exhibitTitle>
    <linkedAsset href="path/to/file.xml" />
</exhibit>
```

**External XML File:**

```
<externalAsset editable="true" id="U10250926378W6C">
    <img src="path/to/image.png" />
    <caption>Some default image</caption>
<externalAsset>
```

I tried applying the following XSLT to the **main XML file**:

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:template match="linkedAsset">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="cus:getFileByUri(./@href)" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="img">
    <xsl:text>|-- Begin Image Source --|</xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="./src" />
    </xsl:text>|-- End Image Source --|</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```

The result was simply "Some default image".

To make sure I was getting an XML structure, and not just the value of all the nodes (or something) I tried:

```
<xsl:template match="linkedAsset">
    <xsl:copy-of select="cus:getFileByUri(./@href)" />
</xsl:template>
```

Which returned the original external XML file structure:

```
<externalAsset editable="true" id="U10250926378W6C">
    <img src="path/to/image.png" />
    <caption>Some default image</caption>
<externalAsset>
```

I also tried:

```
<xsl:template match="linkedAsset">
    <xsl:value-of select="cus:getFileByUri(./@href)//img/@src" />
</xsl:template>
```

Which returned "path/to/image.png" as expected.

Finally, based on answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20329594/how-can-i-apply-an-xslt-template-to-a-string), I tried the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:template match="linkedAsset">
    <xsl:call-template name="renderExternal">
        <xsl:with-param name="asset" select="cus:getFileByUri(./@href)" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template name="renderExternal">
    <xsl:param name="asset" select="." />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="$asset" />
</xsl:template>
```

The output was identical to the original `apply-template`.

*Is there any way to apply `apply-templates` to a value returned from a function?  I can clearly send the string to `copy-of`, `value-of`, and even perform xpaths on it; can I simply not use it with `apply-templates`?*

---

**EXPLANATION OF CHOSEN ANSWER**

As it turns out, the solution to my problem was pretty specific (I was applying a template to a node that matched that same template, and that wouldn't be clear from the simplified versions of the code I provided).  I really earned my -1 on this one.  *ANYWAY*, I feel that keshlam's answer will be the most helpful to people visiting this question in the future, as it answers what I THOUGHT my problem was.

Comment: "*Is there any way to achieve this?*" What exactly is "this"? If it's hiding somewhere between all those things you tried and didn't work, I sure missed it. The fact that you are using an unknown function doesn't help either. Is it at all relevant to what you're trying to achieve here?

Comment: @michael.hor257k Yeah, sorry about the function, I guess I really don't know enough about XSLT to know how functions work, I just assumed they all returned strings (the tests I did above were to test that).  Anyway, I *think* I said what I *this* was in the first two sentences, although if I can convince you to lift that -1 by clarifying, I'll gladly do what it takes (I've made some minor changes, I hope they help).

Comment: You cannot convince me to lift the -1, because I didn't put it there. Briefly, not all functions return strings; some return other data types. Of special interest here are *result-tree-fragment* and *node-set* types. At no point in your question do we see what the actual result returned by the function is. Note that seeing it does not necessarily mean knowing what data type it is - but it would be a start. Why don't you call `<xsl:copy-of select="cus:getFileByUri(./@href)"/>` and post the result?

Comment: @michael.hor257k  I mentioned that I put it through `copy-of` and got back the original external XML document, but you're right, I should include the actual output in the question.  I'll see if I can knock off some extra stuff to make room for it.  As for `node-set`, @keshlam suggested that, and I've been trying to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To execute apply-templates against it, your extension has to return the XML to the stylesheet in already-parsed form (typically a DOM tree or NodeIterator) In XSLT 1.0, you may then have to apply the `exslt:node-set()` extension function, or your processor's equivalent of that, to handle the impedence mismatch between Temporary Trees and Node Sets (xsl:apply-templates operates on nodesets).

Details of writing and registering extensions may vary from processor to processor. If you're using Xalan-J, for example, see https://xml.apache.org/xalan-j/extensions.html

Comment: My problem turned out to be something else entirely, but this is certainly the best answer to what I *thought* my problem was.  Thanks!